# How can I apply a PowerPoint VBA script to a selection of shapes?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'd like to select a number of shapes on a slide, to then run a macro on all selected shapes. For example: I'd like to increase the shapes' animation delay time by a given value.
Note: Some shapes may have more than one animation.

So far, I've got the following code. It does the trick, but it does it for all shapes on the current slide.

```
Sub ActiveSlideShapes_DelayInc()
    Dim osld   As Slide
    Dim i      As Long
    Dim a      As Integer
    Dim oeff   As Effect
    Const sngDel As Single = 0.1

    Set osld = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1)

    For i = osld.TimeLine.MainSequence.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set oeff = osld.TimeLine.MainSequence(i)
        With oeff
            .Timing.TriggerDelayTime = .Timing.TriggerDelayTime + sngDel
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Another solution could be to select the actual TimeLine elements instead of shapes. And then do a "For...Next" loop only on those selected animations. This would be the more elegant solution for when certain shapes have several different animations attached to them. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the selection.shaperange, it should loop through each shape that is selected.

```
For Each Shp In Selection.ShapeRange
 With Shp
            .Timing.TriggerDelayTime = .Timing.TriggerDelayTime + sngDel
        End With
Next
```

Comment: This gives me a compile error: "Method or data member not found." with the second ".Timing" highlighted as the error. (Which is weird... if anything, I'd expect the first instance of ".Timing" to produce the error).

Comment: Since sngDel is a constant, could you try to replace it with 0.1 in the code?

Comment: Shape objects have no .Timing property, which is what the error message is trying to tell you.  I'd imagine that the error occurs on the second instance of .Timing because you're asking it to read that property's value before applying it in the first instance.

Comment: While I don't know much about animation in PPT, could you explain this from the Microsoft support site.   "You can apply multiple animation effects to a single string of text or an object, such as a picture, shape, or SmartArt graphic."

Comment: It doesn't work with 0.1 either.
@Steve Rindsberg: if Shape objects don't have a .Timing property, does this mean this won't be possible at all?

Comment: I don't know that it won't be possible, but not exactly in this way.  Have a look at Shyam Pillai's VBA tips, scroll down to the one that starts out with "Timeline" ... that may help.  http://www.skphub.com/vba.htm#.Wj0z0XlOnGg